# Custom elements cannot access it's contents in the shadowRoot

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I tried to access contents of my custom element in another custom elemnent shadow root.

`index.html` just has a `my-tag-wrapper` element:

```dart
<!-- import HTMLs and init Polymer-->
...
<my-tag-wrapper></my-tag-wrapper>
...
```

`my_tag_wrapper.html` contains a `my-tag` element with a paragraph element:

```dart
<polymer-element name="my-tag-wrapper" >
  <template>
    <my-tag>
      <p>wrapped my-tag contents</p>
    </my-tag>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="my_tag_wrapper.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

`my_tag.html` just render it's contents:

```dart
<polymer-element name="my-tag" >
  <template>
    <content></content>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="my_tag.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

`my_tag.dart` will print it's contents to console:

```dart
@CustomTag('my-tag')
class MyTagElement extends PolymerElement {
  ParagraphElement get p => this.querySelector('p');

  MyTagElement.created() : super.created() {
    var pe = p;
    var t = (pe == null) ? null : pe.text;
    print('my-tag p: ${t}');
    print('my-tag outerHtml: ${outerHtml}');
  }
}
```

However, `my_tag.dart` print:

```
my-tag p: null
my-tag outerHtml: <my-tag></my-tag>
```

Can I get `my-tag` contents in above codes?

Here is [the example repo](https://github.com/kui/polymer-dart-question-sample).

## Edit:

I understood this problem with the clue provided by [@Günter Zöchbauer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24888437/3864351).

In the other shadowRoot, the contents of custom elements **cannot be accessible on the `created()` constructor**. The contents is accessible on and after `attached()`.

I fixed `my_tag.dart`:

```dart
@CustomTag('my-tag')
class MyTagElement extends PolymerElement {
  ParagraphElement get p => this.querySelector('p');

  MyTagElement.created() : super.created() {
    _printContent(); // print null because contents is not rendered
  }

  @override
  attached() {
    super.attached();
    _printContent(); // print contents
  }

  _printContent() {
    var pe = p;
    var t = (pe == null) ? null : pe.text;
    print('my-tag p: ${t}');
    print('my-tag outerHtml: ${outerHtml}');
  }
}
```

I had a misunderstanding that a contents of a custom element is always accessible on `created()` constructor because the contents of `my-tag` is accessible on `created()` when it is a child in `body` element.

Edit: `s/domReady/attached` by [the @Günter Zöchbauer's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887092/custom-elements-cannot-access-its-contents-in-the-shadowroot/24888437?noredirect=1#comment38665221_24888437)

Answer (score 2):

Because `my-tag` as a `content` node `p` becomes a child of `my-tag-wrapper.shadowRoot`.

You can access it using

```dart
(shadowRoot.querySelector('content') as ContentElement).getDistributedNodes()[0];
```

Comment: I found that `my-tag` can access it's contents without `shadowRoot`. however, by this answer, I noticed that these contents is not rendered on `created()` constructor. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are right. `this.querySelector` should do. In the `created` constructor almost nothing is rendered you shouldn't do anything here beside the initialization of some class fields. Currently the best option is `attached` when you want to access the DOM but only after the `super.attached();` call.

Comment: I confirmed that invaking `attached()` is earlier than `domReady()`. So, I fixed my solution. Thanks again.